# finding number of distinct integers in a sequence

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve this problem which requires me to find the number of distinct integers in a sequence given by $a_n = a_{n-1}*p + q$ with $a_0 = s$ and $p,q,s$  in $\mathbb{Z}$
so far this is the approach I've been taking:
$a_n = p^n*s + \sum_{i=0}^{i=n-1} p^nq$.
so im looking for some $m,n$ s.t
$a_{m+n} = a_n$.
by substituting $a_n$ from above and trying to solve $a_{m+n} - a_n = 0$ and I got $sp^n(p^m -1) + \sum_{n}^{m+n-1}p^nq$.
im really quite unsure about how to try to solve this problem so any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If $p=0$, the sequence runs 
$$s,q,q,q,\ldots $$
and has either one or two distinct integers ($s=q$ or not?).
If $p=1$, it runs
$$s,s+q,s+2q,\ldots, s+nq,\ldots $$
and has either one or infinitely many distinct integers ($q=0$ or not?).
If $p=-1$, it runs
$$ s,q-s,s,q-s,s,q-s,\ldots$$
and has one or two distinct integers ($q=2s$ or not?).

For all other $p$, note that $p^n$ is unbounded and so usually is (using your result)
$$ \begin{align}a_n&=p^ns+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^kq\\&=p^ns+\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}q\\&=\frac{p^n\bigl((p-1)s+q\bigr)-q}{p-1}\end{align}$$
(and so will have infinitely many distinct integers).
 The only exception is when $(p-1)s+q=0$, in which case $a_n=s$ and there is only one distinct integer.

---

In summary, the answer is

- **one** if $q=(1-p)s$
- **two** if $p=0$, $q\ne s$ or if $p=-1$, $q=2s$
- **infinitely many** otherwise

Comment: thank you so much for this thorough explanation